# Would women be seen as expendable as men in a world with artificial wombs?

Tags: society, science-fiction, military

My world is about 500 years ahead of ours in terms of technology, with a notable bit of tech being the artificial womb. A sperm and an egg are placed in one and a baby develops in their over the span of several months. It is common for all babies to be born this way in this world. Natural births are seen as very strange and hippieish. My world is also high militarized following a monster driven apocalypse that practically destroyed all society. All citizens of the empire than spans this world are required to give up 5 years of their lives in service to either the military, police force, or national guard. In this world, would the loss of female lives not be viewed as negatively as it is in ours with the addition of artificial wombs?

Comment: Can you give evidence for the assumption you've made that in our world the loss of Female lives is more negative than male lives?

Comment: @Mathaddict I base my statement only on my experience living in modern times. I don't view it as a negative or a positive, just something I believe to be true

Comment: @Mathaddict This is quite a strange request - here as the milky way, solar system, earth - things are as follows - no women -> no children  -> no workers on factory -> no production -> no laptops -> no hardware to play games on -> sad humans.

Comment: @MolbOrg Just to clarify **no men** -> no children -> no workers on factory -> no production -> no laptops -> no hardware to play games on -> sad humans is an equally valid statement.

Comment: It's easy to take and store sperm, eggs, not so easy.

Comment: Whether a life is expendible depends on whether the said life is in power or not. Not gender, race, orientation, just power.

Comment: VTC:Opinion-Based, but it might be more accurate to say it's story-based. As the author, you can create the circumstances that justify any answer to this question. There isn't (and cannot be) "one right answer" because you haven't provided the book-length description of the philosophies, politics, religion, traditions, cultures, and history of your world. BTW, keep in mind that historically here on Earth (and generalizing across a planet with thousands of cultures... see the problem?), women have always been perceived as being more disposable than men. Hence the fight for equality.

Comment: wow looking at some comments we definitely need the question, seems people forgot what evolution necessities are and what survival of species means, and how it happens.  definitely, vote for keeping the question, it has quite a scientific and not opinion-based basis, which can be used in answers.

Comment: @Mathaddict You might want to check the theory of [male expendability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Male_expendability). Many theorists of masculinity also support this view at least to some extent. You might also want to consider that the reproductive bottleneck depends on the number of women more than on the number of men.

Comment: VTO: I think this is a great worldbuilding question that can be answered based on existing theories of gender. The answers do not have to be purely speculation-based. I also think that the proposed frame challenge (that women have always been perceived as being more disposable than men) has no basis in reality or academic research and scholarship (search returns results about men being disposable). All human societies I am aware of (except mythological) were protecting women. I think the author of the proposal confuses 'disposable' with 'lacking power or agency'.

Answer (score 3):

**Eventually, yes.**

Historically, females have been seen as a critical resource to any civilization because population growth has always been limited by the number of females of child-bearing age, who can produce no more than (roughly) one child per year each—and usually far less in practice.

Men have no such anatomical limit, or at least it is so high as to not matter, so they are expendable in wars or dangerous jobs. No matter how few survive, they are sufficient men left to produce the next generation.

If you remove the anatomical limit on female fertility, then women become just as expendable as men. It may take quite some time for culture to recognize that, but it would likely happen on the same timescale as seeing natural gestation as “hippieish”.

Answer (score 1):

People aren't as utilitarian as that.

Men would probably still like women around because men think women are pretty and smell nice and their hair is soft.

Now if you're going for a really grimdark world where such feelings don't exist, then removing women from the world would add to that feeling, as some military or gangster or other grimdark fiction has no women.

Comment: Worlds where there is nothing *but* women can also be particularly grimdark. “The Stars are Legion” by Kameron Hurley is the first example that comes to mind, though in that case everyone is a woman precisely because it maximises the available number of wombs…